# Push Notifications wont work on distribution

Tags: iphone, push-notification, distribution

Ok now I have a problem with the push notifications. I have set them successfully for the developing part and I was receiving them on my device. Now I have the application on app store and I cant receave notifications.
This is step by step what I did:

-I have created a provisioning profile for distribution and connected it to the app id that has push notifications for distribution and development.

-I have built the app for distribution with that provisioning profile.

-I have submitted the app on app store.

-Now I have 2 certificates in keychain access Apple Production IOS Push Service:AppID and iPhone Distribution:CompanyName

-I have made .pem file from both and tested it with both. No notification has arrived

I really have no idea what to try and how to fix this.

Comment: Well the push notifications don't arrive to the devices but this is only in distribution mode. It worked perfectly in develop mode> I have changed only the .pem file as I was supposed to and the ssl link as it is in Apple's guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar problems, just a few weeks ago. For me the case was that I had several provisioning profiles left in xCode. So what I needed to do was:

- Go to Organizer -> Devices -> Provisioning Profiles
- Select my distribution profiles for the app in question, and delete them.
- Go to developer.apple.com/iOS
- Go to the distribution profile, modify it.
- Just clicked "select all" (so I could re-save it with no changes), somehow the profile needed to be re-created AFTER enabling the Push certificate
- Download the new profile and install it to xCode
- Clean project under Product -> Clean

Now I made a new release and tested it and it worked. Maybe this workes for you as well.

***Edit***
The red-thread in this answer is that when Push notification in the App is enabled, the provisioning profiles need to be re-done (even though, to the eye there are no changes).

Comment: hi, I want to know what do you mean by "made a new release". Is it a new distribution to App store or Ad-Hoc? I can't run a release version on my iPhone.

Comment: In today's XCode, that would be a new Archive. In XCode 4.5.2 you choose the provisioning profile later on.

Comment: Except the "gateway.push.apple.com", what else should I change when I distribute my app? I still can't get my notification work.

Comment: Provisioning profile should be the most updated one (as stated in my answer). Best is to create a new question with your problem. Be sure to inform about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If using Parse, make sure you have uploaded your iOS Production Certificate. I ran into this issue and discovered a week later that I had only uploaded my iOS Development Certs to the server.

**Settings > Push > Apple Push Certificates**

You need to see something that has a Certificate Type of iOS Production with a valid expiration date.