# Having issue in push notification in ios

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am getting push notification in developer mode but while i distribute app to app store

i am not able to get notification.

I have made both profiles for development and distributions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push Notifications wont work on distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634982/push-notifications-wont-work-on-distribution)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504726/apple-push-notification-is-not-working-for-distribution-but-working-for-developm

Comment: Hey...also not getting any error..already followed the steps  from that post

Comment: @Gamex you need to redo the certificates and use the production gateway  not the sanbox one

Comment: you may get solution by visiting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156873/push-notification-in-ios/39368761#39368761