# Not receiving push notification while using distribution adhoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am getting push notification while using development provisioning profile.

when i switch to distribution provisioning profile i did not get push notification.

my app id is same for both development and distribution profiles.
I created separate apns certificates for both development and distribution, but i am not getting push notification.

why it happened like this.
Please give your suggestions to find out the solution for this problem.

Comment: Are you getting device token from APNS?? (For distribution profile)

Comment: also tell whether you are changing the production to true in your server with a separate .p12 or pem

Comment: I think . you might have missed any of the step while creating "pem" file .. 
You should cross check the procedure.

Comment: you need to ask server guy to change the pem file acc to production and also set url may be right now it's pointing to sandbox you have to change it to live.

Comment: if you are getting apns token using distribution.. and created your pem well then there is problem with your server.. change the production mode to true and also replace the pem or .p12(for java).

Comment: i created separate pem and p12 files, and i am getting device token for distribution profile. I have a sample php file, i am testing in mac terminal using that php file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634982/push-notifications-wont-work-on-distribution check this once @Goutham

Comment: I tried this 3 times and I deleted old distribution profile and created new one, but no use @i_Satya

Comment: Is server also changing certificate from Dev to Production? There are chances, server still using .pem file of Development. @Goutham

Comment: @Goutham have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: Yup, I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer below links:

1. [ios-push-notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications)
2. [apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

These links may help you

Comment: I followed and did what steps in above links.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same app id for development and distribution mode.

1. Then use the same .CSR file to generate production certificate and
2. Use the production certificate and .p12 file generated from that .CSR file to make .pem file.

[For more information you can follow this tutorial, where you can test if you have made a valid .pem file.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and tried different approaches from net.But no luck. Because the solution may vary from person to person. 
Try different approaches.

This approach solved my problem:

While creating Production SSL certificate, do not change the name "aps_production.cer".

And before creating Development related certificates, first create certificates(SSL,provisioning,p12) for only production.

And also use the same ".certSigningRequest" file for both development and production. No need to create two files.

It really worked for me after trying different approaches. Give it a try.